# Agrupar array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, ecmascript-6

Estoy intentando agrupar un array de objetos a partir de un `parentId` que trae cada elemento del array, el resultado que espero es el que tengo en el output.

He hecho el primer nivel y me crea bien el primer subgrupo de `chlds` pero no veo la forma de que me genere los siguientes. Gracias de antemano!

INPUT

```
const data = [
{
    "groupid": 1,
    "parentid": 0,
    "usrdesc": "Principal"
},
{
    "groupid": 43,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "Opers"
},
{
    "groupid": 44,
    "parentid": 43,
    "usrdesc": "London"
},
{
    "groupid": 45,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "Sells"
},
{
    "groupid": 46,
    "parentid": 45,
    "usrdesc": "grp"
},
{
    "groupid": 89,
    "parentid": 46,
    "usrdesc": "PFG"
},
{
    "groupid": 48,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "WEF"
},
{
    "groupid": 49,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "API"
},
{
    "groupid": 50,
    "parentid": 49,
    "usrdesc": "CTX"
},
{
    "groupid": 142,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "CSS"
},
{
    "groupid": 58,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "ASD"
},
{
    "groupid": 71,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "CZX"
},
{
    "groupid": 106,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "RTE"
},
{
    "groupid": 140,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "NIO"
},
{
    "groupid": 148,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "ADGB"
},
{
    "groupid": 62,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "OUS"
},
{
    "groupid": 136,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "BGE"
},
{
    "groupid": 137,
    "parentid": 136,
    "usrdesc": "PDS"
},
{
    "groupid": 138,
    "parentid": 136,
    "usrdesc": "DVE"
}
]
```

OUTPUT (deseado)

```
const response = [
{
    "groupid": 1,
    "parentid": 0,
    "usrdesc": "Principal",
    "chlds": [
        {
            "groupid": 43,
            "parentid": 1,
            "usrdesc": "Opers",
            "chlds": [
                {
                    "groupid": 44,
                    "parentid": 43,
                    "usrdesc": "London",
                    "chlds": [
                        {
                            "groupid": 45,
                            "parentid": 44,
                            "usrdesc": "Sells",
                            "chlds": [
                                {
                                    "groupid": 46,
                                    "parentid": 45,
                                    "usrdesc": "grp",
                                    "chlds": [
                                        {
                                            "groupid": 89,
                                            "parentid": 46,
                                            "usrdesc": "PFG"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "groupid": 48,
                            "parentid": 44,
                            "usrdesc": "WEF"
                        },
                        {
                            "groupid": 49,
                            "parentid": 44,
                            "usrdesc": "API",
                            "chlds": [
                                {
                                    "groupid": 50,
                                    "parentid": 49,
                                    "usrdesc": "CTX"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "groupid": 142,
                            "parentid": 44,
                            "usrdesc": "CSS"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "groupid": 58,
            "parentid": 1,
            "usrdesc": "ASD",
            "chlds": [
                {
                    "groupid": 71,
                    "parentid": 58,
                    "usrdesc": "CZX"
                },
                {
                    "groupid": 106,
                    "parentid": 58,
                    "usrdesc": "RTE"
                },
                {
                    "groupid": 140,
                    "parentid": 58,
                    "usrdesc": "NIO"
                },
                {
                    "groupid": 148,
                    "parentid": 58,
                    "usrdesc": "ADGB"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "groupid": 62,
            "parentid": 1,
            "usrdesc": "OUS"
        },
        {
            "groupid": 136,
            "parentid": 1,
            "usrdesc": "BGE",
            "chlds": [
                {
                    "groupid": 137,
                    "parentid": 136,
                    "usrdesc": "PDS"
                },
                {
                    "groupid": 138,
                    "parentid": 136,
                    "usrdesc": "DVE"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Mi código

```
const nested = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
if (item.parentid === 0) {
  return [...acc, item];
} else {
  const parentIndex = acc.findIndex(parent => parent.groupid === item.parentid);
  const parent = acc[parentIndex];
  if (parentIndex >= 0) {
    const children = parent.children ?? [];
    return Object.assign([], acc, {
      [parentIndex]: {
        ...parent,
        children: [...children, item],
      },
    });
  }
  return acc
}
  }, []);
```

---

EDIT:

He editado un poco la función para hacerla recursiva pero me itera siempre sobre el mismo elemento.

Código:

```
const nestedIndex = (item, array) => {
  let copy = [...array]
  const index = copy.findIndex(el => el.groupid === item.parentid)
  if (index >= 0) {
    const chlds = copy[index].chlds ? [...copy[index].chlds, item] : [item]
    copy[index].chlds = chlds
    return copy
  } else {
     const response =  copy.map(itemNested => {
       if (itemNested.chlds) {
         const response = nestedIndex(item, [...itemNested.chlds])
         return response
       } else {
         return itemNested
       }
     })
     return response    
  }
}

const nested = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      if (curr.parentid === 0) {
        return [...prev, curr];
      } else {
        return nestedIndex(curr, prev)
      }
    }, [])
}

const me = nested(data)
```

Comment: Quizás sería adecuado poner un ejemplo de como sería el resultado final de lo que deseas obtener basado en el objeto inicial, de esa manera será más fácil poder ir en el camino correcto y ayudarte lo antes posible.

Comment: Esta añadido, el valor inicial es el input y el deseado es el output

Comment: Mmm... Bajo qué caso ```chlds``` tendría dos elementos?

Comment: Dependiendo de el número de elementos que lo tengan de `parentid`

Comment: Pero por ejemplo hay 2 con ```parentId```de 44 pero no están en el mismo array.

Comment: Lo acabo de revisar, y el objeto con `groupid` 44 tiene 4 elementos dentro, que a su vez estos tienen algunos subelementos de los que son `parentid`, es posible que no se diferencie muy bien y entiendo que como el output es bastante grande de pie a confusiones, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he hecho con dos funciones, la primera mira que no haya mas posibles opciones en el primer nivel, ya que no lo añadi en el ejemplo pero es posible que me lleguen dos o mas elementos como `Principal`.

```js
const data = [
{
    "groupid": 1,
    "parentid": 0,
    "usrdesc": "Principal"
},
{
    "groupid": 43,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "Opers"
},
{
    "groupid": 44,
    "parentid": 43,
    "usrdesc": "London"
},
{
    "groupid": 45,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "Sells"
},
{
    "groupid": 46,
    "parentid": 45,
    "usrdesc": "grp"
},
{
    "groupid": 89,
    "parentid": 46,
    "usrdesc": "PFG"
},
{
    "groupid": 48,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "WEF"
},
{
    "groupid": 49,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "API"
},
{
    "groupid": 50,
    "parentid": 49,
    "usrdesc": "CTX"
},
{
    "groupid": 142,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "CSS"
},
{
    "groupid": 58,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "ASD"
},
{
    "groupid": 71,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "CZX"
},
{
    "groupid": 106,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "RTE"
},
{
    "groupid": 140,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "NIO"
},
{
    "groupid": 148,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "ADGB"
},
{
    "groupid": 62,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "OUS"
},
{
    "groupid": 136,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "BGE"
},
{
    "groupid": 137,
    "parentid": 136,
    "usrdesc": "PDS"
},
{
    "groupid": 138,
    "parentid": 136,
    "usrdesc": "DVE"
}
]

function attachChildrenByItem (item, data) {
  const children = data
    .filter(d => d.parentid === item.groupid)
    .map(d => attachChildrenByItem(d, data))

  return children.length ? { ...item, children } : item
}

function attachChildren (data) {
  return data.filter(item => {
    const index = data.findIndex(itemNested => itemNested['groupid'] === item.parentid)
    if (index <= -1) {
      return true
    } 
  }).map(d => attachChildrenByItem(d, data))
}
console.log(attachChildren(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

Basándome en la respuesta casi correcta de @AmilcalBarrera, he realizado la siguiente modificación para cumplir estrictamente con el output deseado:

```js
const data = [
{
    "groupid": 1,
    "parentid": 0,
    "usrdesc": "Principal"
},
{
    "groupid": 43,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "Opers"
},
{
    "groupid": 44,
    "parentid": 43,
    "usrdesc": "London"
},
{
    "groupid": 45,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "Sells"
},
{
    "groupid": 46,
    "parentid": 45,
    "usrdesc": "grp"
},
{
    "groupid": 89,
    "parentid": 46,
    "usrdesc": "PFG"
},
{
    "groupid": 48,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "WEF"
},
{
    "groupid": 49,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "API"
},
{
    "groupid": 50,
    "parentid": 49,
    "usrdesc": "CTX"
},
{
    "groupid": 142,
    "parentid": 44,
    "usrdesc": "CSS"
},
{
    "groupid": 58,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "ASD"
},
{
    "groupid": 71,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "CZX"
},
{
    "groupid": 106,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "RTE"
},
{
    "groupid": 140,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "NIO"
},
{
    "groupid": 148,
    "parentid": 58,
    "usrdesc": "ADGB"
},
{
    "groupid": 62,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "OUS"
},
{
    "groupid": 136,
    "parentid": 1,
    "usrdesc": "BGE"
},
{
    "groupid": 137,
    "parentid": 136,
    "usrdesc": "PDS"
},
{
    "groupid": 138,
    "parentid": 136,
    "usrdesc": "DVE"
}
]

function haschilds(groupid, arr) {
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].parentid == groupid) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false
}

function convertir(data, parentid){
    let response = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].parentid == parentid){
            let obj = {
                "groupid": data[i].groupid,
                "parentid": data[i].parentid,
                "usrdesc": data[i].usrdesc
            }
            if(haschilds(data[i].groupid, data)) {
              obj.chlds = convertir(data, data[i].groupid)
            }
            response.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return response;
}
console.log(convertir(data, 0))
```

Como se puede apreciar, he agregado la función `haschilds` para que devuelva un valor booleano en caso de que los tenga o no.

```js
function haschilds(groupid, arr) {
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].parentid == groupid) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Luego, dentro de la función `convertir` he separado la propiedad `chlds` durante la creación del objeto, para ponerla en un condicional que evalua si realmente tiene o no tiene hijos mediante la función `haschild` mostrada más arriba.

Si hay hijos se agrega la propiedad, y en caso contrario no, dejándolo tal como el OP muestra en su OUTPUT.

El mérito, aun así, es de @Amilcar y no mio, tan solo he realizado esta aportación para pulir su respuesta, que si tiene a bien incluirlo en ella yo encantado de eliminar la mia.

Answer (score 2):

Muy buenas noches, este va a ser mi primer post en la comunidad, espero que te ayude la siguiente funciòn:

```
function convertir(data, parentid){
    let response = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].parentid == parentid){
            let obj = {
                "groupid": data[i].groupid,
                "parentid": data[i].parentid,
                "usrdesc": data[i].usrdesc,
                "chlds": convertir(data, data[i].groupid)
            }
            response.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Un saludo y un abrazo enorme!!!

Comment: He agregado una respuesta basándome en tu código para corregir la tuya, pues dejabas creadas propiedades `chlds` creadas pero sin contenido. Si quieres copia la parte que te faltaba por pulir y edita tu respuesta agregándolo, y así borro la mia, y te llevas todo el mérito, que considero tuyo.  De paso, explica mínimamente tu código y léete [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  para entender cómo se deben responder las preguntas, con solo el código no siempre vale, una explicación ayuda a que la respuesta no sea de baja calidad.

Comment: Buen aporte! usar un for en este caso sería una opción correcta. Aunque en mi caso he creado una opción que encaja mas en lo que buscaba.

Comment: @RicardoAlvarado si tienes una respuesta válida distinta deberias compartirla con la comunidad agregándola en las respuestas de esta pregunta, y creo que en 12 horas la puedes aceptar tu mismo (aunque la pregunta sea tuya)

Comment: Publicada!!! 